# Is it possible to overwrite or monkey-patch gethostbyname in Perl so that it supports IPv6?

Tags: perl, ipv6, gethostbyname

I have a given [application which uses Perl's `gethostbyname` to check if a hostname exists in DNS](https://sources.debian.net/src/backuppc/3.3.1-4/bin/BackupPC_dump/#L496). I don't want to patch the source code of that application not written by me. But I think about overwriting `gethostbyname` in one of the Perl-written configuration files.

So I wonder if there's a chance to overwrite that function by monkey-patching it in some way.

The [documentation of that application says that its hostname lookups work as follows](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/faq/BackupPC.html#How-BackupPC-Finds-Hosts):

```
$ perl -e 'print(gethostbyname("ipv6.google.com") ? "ok\n" : "not found\n");'
not found
```

So far I tried:

```
$ perl -E 'use Socket qw(:DEFAULT getaddrinfo); sub gethostbyname { my ($err, @result) = getaddrinfo(@_); return @result; }; print(gethostbyname("ipv6.google.com") ? "ok\n" : "not found\n");'
not found
```

And:

```
$ perl -E 'use Socket qw(:DEFAULT getaddrinfo); use Monkey::Patch::Action qw(patch_package); patch_package("*", "gethostbyname", "add", sub { my ($err, @result) = getaddrinfo(@_); return @result; }); print(gethostbyname("ipv6.google.com") ? "ok\n" : "not found\n");'
not found
```

(I also tried `main` instead of `*` and `replace` instead of `add`. `replace` bailed out as follows: `Replacing *::gethostbyname: must already exist at /usr/share/perl5/Monkey/Patch/Action.pm line 31.`)

Comment: In the second snippet, all you need is `use subs qw( gethostbyname );`.

Comment: In the third snippet, I think wrapping `patch_package` with a `BEGIN` will do.

Comment: But you probably want to patch from outside the module that has the calls to `gethostbyname` (or you'd simply call the right sub instead). You can do that by naming your override `CORE::GLOBAL::gethostbyname` (before the module using `gethostbyname` is loaded). See [Overriding Built-in Functions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Overriding-Built-in-Functions). You can use `caller` to only provide the override to select modules.

Comment: I actually also played around with `BEGIN { }`, but Ican't remember if it was with `patch_package` or only with `sub gethostbyname { }`. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 3):

TL;TR: That's not explaining how to override `gethostbyname` (the existing comments should help doing that) but instead explaining that this does not fix your actual problem of making this specific code IPv6 ready.

---

First, what should a IPv6 ready `gethostbyname` return? With IPv4 it returns a packed IPv4 address and that's expected by code calling `gethostbyname`. Such code will usually be followed by use of `sockaddr_in`, `PF_INET` sockets etc. But with IPv6 this code instead needs to use `sockaddr_in6` and `PF_INET6` which means it is not enough to patch `gethostbyname`.

And, looking further into the code you have to fix this is actually the case. You just linked in your question to a call of `gethostbyname`  which only checks if it returns a defined value. But if you look [further in the code](https://sources.debian.net/src/backuppc/3.3.1-4/lib/BackupPC/Lib.pm/#L713) you'll see explicit use of `inet_aton`, `PF_INET` sockets etc, i.e. everything assuming IPv4 only addresses.

Comment: Thanks for catching this. I didn't cause I was in a rush, but that's why I posted comments instead of an answer :)

Comment: Thanks for digging that deep. I indeed thought it's solely checking if a hostname resolves or not and that hence the actual type of the return value is irrelevant.